# Passing data from view via view model to controller always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

When passing data from my form to my controller the value is always null. The view model holds 4 different models needed to be displayed and used but when trying to bind back on a post nothing is posted back to the controller. When just using the timetable model it works but when using the timetable object within the view model the properties are always null.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> TimeTable([Bind("TeacherId,DateOfLesson,SubjectDetails,Test")]CourseViewModel timeTable)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(timeTable.ClassTime);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(TimeTable));
    }

    return View(timeTable);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IndividualSubject> individualSubjects { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Student> User { get; set; }

    public TimeTable ClassTime { get; set; }

    public List<DateTime> CalDateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
}
```

View:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CalDateTimes)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" style="width: 25%" class="border-right">
                    @item.Date.ToString("dddd dd MMM yyyy")
                </th>
                <td style="width: 75%">
                    <form asp-controller="IndividualSubjects" asp-action="TimeTable" method="post" role="form">
                        <input type="hidden" value="2" asp-for="ClassTime.TeacherId" name="TeacherId" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="@item" asp-for="ClassTime.DateOfLesson" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="200" asp-for="ClassTime.Duration" />
                        <select class="form-control border-dark custom-select-sm float-left" id="monthSelection" style="width: 20%" asp-for="ClassTime.SubjectDetails">

                            @foreach (var subjects in Model.individualSubjects)
                            {
                                <option value="@subjects.SubjectId">@subjects.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add lesson" class="btn btn-primary float-right" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't find a definitive source, but most likely `bind` does not drill into properties of properties so it is not finding any `TeacherId`, `DateOfLesson`, etc. Additionally problematic is that your properties are enumerables of types, not a single instance. Even if `bind` was smart enough to locate properties of properties I doubt it would go another level and do so on lists. Regardless, [here is a good argument for not using bind at all](https://cpratt.co/stop-using-bind/).

Comment: Thanks, removing bind worked.

Comment: You can still guard against over-posting by crafting a viewmodel that only contains the items you need.